# Redirect to list view after updating list item using SPServices.js

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, spservices

I created a custom form to submit list item and attach multiple attachments.

And would need to redirect user to default list view after all the attachments are attached to a list item.
I tried adding window.location.href='default List url' but it redirects while the attachments are getting added.
It works fine for small file(s) but for large file(s), only 1 attachment gets added.
Here is the snippet:
HTML:

```js
var ListTitle = "SubTask";

$( document ).ready(function() {
//$('#attachment').multifile();
    $("#NewSaveItem").click(function() {
    CreateNewItem();
         
});
    
    
});

function CreateNewItem() {
    var data = {
        __metadata: { 'type': "SP.Data.SubTaskListItem" },
        Title: $('#Title').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        //_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl get current SharePoint site url
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + ListTitle + "')/Items",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        // to make sync calls.
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.ID != undefined && data.d.ID > 0){
                //Uploads files to SharePoint List item
                UploadFileToListItem(data.d);
                
                }
            else
            {
                console.log('Item added successfully');
                }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log('Problem saving data');
        }
    });
   // window.location.href = 'https://connect.sharepoint.com/sites/SpApps/Lists/SubTask/';

}



//Once the item is created now let’s try to upload documents to SharePoint list item.

function UploadFileToListItem(data) {
    var element = document.getElementById("attachment");
    lastFileName = element.files[element.files.length - 1].name;
    for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
        var file = element.files[i];
        uploadFile(data, file);
    }
    alert('Done');
    window.location.href = 'https://connect.sharepoint.com/sites/SpApps/Lists/SubTask/';
}

//uploads single file at a time.
function uploadFile(data, file) {
    var getFileBuffer = function (file) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
        }

        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

        return deferred.promise();
    };
    
    getFileBuffer(file).then(function (buffer) {
        var binary = "";
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        var i = bytes.byteLength;
        while (i--) {
            binary = String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]) + binary;
        }
        var fileName = file.name;
        var error = ''
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "AddAttachment",
            async: false,
            listName: ListTitle,
            listItemID: data.Id,
            fileName: fileName,
            attachment: btoa(binary),
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                console.log(file.name + " uploaded");
            }
        });
    });
    
    
}
```

```html
<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td  valign="top">
<h3> Name</h3>
</td>  
<td valign="top" style="padding:9px;">  
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="255" id="Title" title="Name" style="width: 96%;" ms-spellcheck-true">  
</td>
</tr>
                                
<tr >
<td >
<span style="font-family: " segoe ui" ,sans-serif; color: #444444">
Click here to attach file
</span> 
<div id="attachFilesHolder ">  
 <input type="file" id="attachment" name="FileUpload" multiple/>
</div>  
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>
<input name="SaveItem" style=" height: 40px; font-size: 15px;" id="NewSaveItem" accesskey="O" onclick="" type="button" value="Click here to submit " target="_self">
</div>
```

Please let me know where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Define a uploadedCount variable in SPServices complete func and then when uploading file to list item, check if the files count in upload box is equal to the uploaded count, then use SetInterval to trace like this:

```
var ListTitle = "SubTask";
var fileCount=0;
var uploadCount=0;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //$('#attachment').multifile();
    $("#NewSaveItem").click(function() {
        CreateNewItem();        
    });      
});

function CreateNewItem() {
    var data = {
        __metadata: { 'type': "SP.Data.SubTaskListItem" },
        Title: $('#Title').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        //_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl get current SharePoint site url
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + ListTitle + "')/Items",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        // to make sync calls.
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.ID != undefined && data.d.ID > 0){
                //Uploads files to SharePoint List item
                UploadFileToListItem(data.d);               
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Item added successfully');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log('Problem saving data');
        }
    });
   // window.location.href = 'https://connect.sharepoint.com/sites/SpApps/Lists/SubTask/';

}

//Once the item is created now let’s try to upload documents to SharePoint list item.
function UploadFileToListItem(data) {
    var element = document.getElementById("attachment");
    lastFileName = element.files[element.files.length - 1].name;

    //file count
    fileCount=element.files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
        var file = element.files[i];
        uploadFile(data, file);
    }
    //alert('Done');
    setInterval(function(){ 
        if(fileCount!=0&&fileCount==uploadCount){
            window.location.href = 'https://connect.sharepoint.com/sites/SpApps/Lists/SubTask/';
        }
    }, 1000);   
}

//uploads single file at a time.
function uploadFile(data, file) {
    var getFileBuffer = function (file) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
        }

        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

        return deferred.promise();
    };

    getFileBuffer(file).then(function (buffer) {
        var binary = "";
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        var i = bytes.byteLength;
        while (i--) {
            binary = String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]) + binary;
        }
        var fileName = file.name;
        var error = ''
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "AddAttachment",
            async: false,
            listName: ListTitle,
            listItemID: data.Id,
            fileName: fileName,
            attachment: btoa(binary),
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                console.log(file.name + " uploaded");
                uploadCount++;
            }
        });
    });     
}
```